# как сделать неактивной хранимую процедуру firebird

Tags: firebird

триггер вот так,

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name INACTIVE;
```

а как быть с ХП?

Answer (score 0):

Хранимую процедуру удалить только.

Ну или не вызывайте ее, она и работать не будет. - Ваш капитан очевидность :D

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб сделать процедуру неактивной, нужно сразу после первого `BEGIN` добавить команду `EXIT`.